# Unable to resolve dependency outside React Native project

Tags: react-native

My rn-cli.config.js looks like so

```
var path = require("path");

var config = {
    extraNodeModules: {
        "react-native": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-native"),
        "react": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react"),
    },
    getProjectRoots() {
        return [
            // Keep your project directory.
            path.resolve(__dirname),
            path.resolve(__dirname, "../someCommonJS"), // path to the external module
        ];
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

However im getting the following error:

> unable to resolve module a.js from myProj/App.js

In `App.js` i import like so
import a from "src/a.js";

My project structure is quite simple:

someCommonJS
--src
----a.js
myProj
--App.js
--rn-cli.config.js

How can i debut this to see whats wrong? (path.resolve) seems to be resolving to the appropriate absolute path.

Comment: Your config seems to be correct. Can you give more info about the structure of your project(s) and the exact output from the packager?

Comment: Yes its quite simple though. Adding it to the main question